# Enter value into cell with an InputBox when a radio button is selected

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button, inputbox

I have a worksheet named "Main" that I would like to have an InputBox to pop up when a radio button is selected; (Option Button 3 with value = 1 in cell A311), and have the value of the InputBox placed into cell R2. I have placed the following code directly into the objects sheet but can get it to only run when I assign the macro directly to the radio button.

```
Sub Pumped_WS()

Dim userinput As String

Set pumped = ActiveSheet.Range("A311")
Set ws = ActiveSheet.Range("R2")

If pumped.Value = 1 Then userinput = Application.InputBox("Please enter elevation for the pumping water surface!")

    ws.Value = userinput

End Sub
```

I would like to set it up as a private sub and run based just on the selection of the radio button without having to assign the button a macro.  When I try:

```
Private Pumped_WS(ByVal target As Range)
```

with the rest of the code in the public sub; nothing happens when the radio button is selected.  Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do - where is the `target` parameter supposed to be coming from? How exactly is clicking on the Option Button supposed to pass a `Range`? This doesn't have anything to do with the visibility of the `Sub` - you can attach the click handler to either a `Public` or `Private` `Sub`.

Comment: Is this radio button a form control? If yes, then why not use the ActiveX control? You can double click the control in design mode to access it's code area where you can put the code